# Java Hashtable based chat application

Tags: java, chat, hashtable

I am using Hashtable for a http chat application using google app engine. I get strange behavior from Hashtable. Sometime it return null when i try to look for an id by using Hashtable.get(id) method. I need your help that is Hastable good for such chat application? Is there any better java data structure for google app engine like chat application? Thank you for your help..

Comment: What is the datatype of `id`?

Comment: [HashTable.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#get(java.lang.Object)). "Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, **or null if this map contains no mapping for the key**."

Answer (score 1):

Hashtable.get(id) will return a null if there is no key of name id in the table, so you need to test for the null. Hashtable is a perfectly fine data structure for an application.

Answer (score 0):

Hashtable is a good choice if your application needs to handle multiple threads simultaneously. Otherwise, people generally use HashMap since time is not wasted in making sure only one thread accesses the data structure. Both of them have excellent performance since lookup time is constant time. You need to make sure that you have filled up the hashtable with required values, otherwise you will get a null value back.